# Added the layout links in the Header Partial File To Signup and Login and Now they don't show up on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, header-files

All,

I added the links in the header file for the users after the individual signup or login. Unfortunately, now the "Log in" or "Sign Up" buttons will not show up on the page anymore. The page has a black dot on the screen in the header where the buttons should be. The code in the header partial file where the if-else statement is listed below.

```
.row#start-project-first-row
    .container
        .row
            .span2
                = link_to image_tag("logo.png", class: "brand", style: "margin-top: 10px;"), static_pages_home_page_path
            .span7
                %ul.nav.nav-tabs
                    %li#about
                        = link_to "About US", static_pages_about_path, id: "about"
                    %li#browse
                        = link_to "Browse", static_pages_browse_path, id: "browse"
                    %li#start                   
                        = link_to "Start", static_pages_start_project_path, id: "start"
                    %li#blog                    
                        = link_to "Blog", '#', id: "blog"

        .span3
            .row-fluid
                .span12
                    %form
                        - if signed_in?
                            %li
                                = link_to "Users", '#'
                            %li#fat-menu.dropdown
                                %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#"}
                                    Account
                                    %b.caret
                                %ul.dropdown-menu
                                    %li
                                        = link_to "Profile", current_user
                                    %li
                                        = link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user)
                                    %li.divider
                                        = link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete"
                        - else
                            %li
                                = link_to "Log in", static_pages_login_path, class: "btn btn-small btn-success"
                                = link_to " Sign up", static_pages_login_path, class: "btn btn-small btn-primary"

            .row-fluid
                .span12
                    %form.form-search
                        %input.input-medium.search-query{type: "text",placeholder: "To search type..."}
                        %i.icon-search
```

Also, an excerpt from the code for the application.js file is listed below.

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

The sessions is listed below.

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You meant, links in `else` statement are not shown after a sign in? Can you show me an screenshot.

Comment: try with `-if user_signed_in?`.

Comment: @anonymousxxx That causes an undefined method error.

Comment: @cortex I cannot submit a screenshot. It stated that I need 10 rep points to attach an image.

Comment: Are you using devise for authentication?

Comment: @anonymousxxx No, I am not using devise for authentication. I also just added my sessions_helper code

Comment: Have you add `include SessionsHelper` to `SessionsController` or `ApplicationController` ?

Comment: @anonymousxxx Yes, I included the SessionsHelper in the ApplicationController.